# How to display message Using if-else condition in Vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

```html
<div class="dimension-section no-border-radius margin-top-2">
  <div class="dimension-size"></div>
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li v-on:click="display = !display" @click="getPartingCharges('5-10')" :class="{ active: isActiveClass, }" class="product-list">5-10 </li>
      <li @click="getPartingCharges('10-22')" :class="{  active: isActiveClass,}" class="product-list">10-22 </li>
      <li @click="getPartingCharges('22-27')" :class="{  active: isActiveClass, }" class="product-list">22-27</li>

    </ul> <span v-if="display">charges will be applied</span>
  </div>

</div>
```

I have 3 li tags, where i need to display message, on click of selected quantity like 5-10,10-22,22-27.

condition is like if user select (5-10) i need to display message like charges apply, Else need to display if user select (10-22)(22-27) need to display message like no charges apply. using if else coditions.

Comment: Checkout v-if https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<span v-if="display">charges will be applied</span>
<span v-else>charges will not be applied</span>
```

I am not sure what you mean. but in vuejs you  can use the if-else statement.
if I can check your code, I will give good answer.

and you should better for "display". this is master boolen value.

Comment: Not necessarily: it can be anything, and it will be evaluated as truthy or falsy in a `v-if` binding.